# Definition of a Basis for topology.

Tags: general-topology

In my textbook (James Munkres, *Topology*) on Topology, I have a definition for a basis for a topology on X where first condition is confusing me:

"1) For each x $\in$ X there is at least one basis element B containing x."

My question: can someone explain in really simple terms the difference between a "basis element B" and an "element x". Intuitivily, I would think of B as a *set* with an element x within it.

I think it is the terminology that confuses me, how is B an element?

Comment: From the set $X$, a set of subsets is selected, let's say $\mathcal{B}$, which we will call the base. Now the sentence can be written as $\forall x \in X, \exists A \in \mathcal{B}, x\in A$.

Comment: So, the base B is an set with x within it? I don't get why they call B an element?

Comment: $B$ is element of $\mathcal{B}$. In other words this property can be written as $\bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}}B=X$

Comment: Sets are elements too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal B$ is a basis of a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, then $\mathcal B$ is a set of elements of $\tau$. So, if we say “one basis element $B$”, we are saying that $B$ is an element of the basis $\mathcal B$. And, when we say “an element $x$”, this means and element $x$ of $X$. So, $B$ and $x$ are elements of distinct sets. And, since $B$ is a set of elements of $X$, it makes sense to say that $B$ contains $x$ (although, in my opinion, it woud be better to say that $x$ is an element of $B$).